# SPIR-V compiler error when trying to use uniform struct as function argument

Tags: struct, compiler-errors, glsl, spir-v

```
#version 400

#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable

layout(location = 0) out vec4 fs_color;

struct Test
{
    float value;
};

layout(std140,set = 0,binding = 0) uniform UTest
{
    Test t;
} u_test;

float get_value(Test t) {return t.value;}

void main()
{
    fs_color = vec4(get_value(u_test.t),0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

The GLSL code above causes the following SPIR-V compiler error:

```
Object: 0x0 | SPIR-V module not valid: OpFunctionCall Argument <id> '29's type does not match Function <id> '8's parameter type.
```

The error comes from the *get_value* function call in *main*. The error happens whenever I try to pass a struct instance as a function argument, if that instance is part of a uniform (In this case *u_test*). If the struct is not part of a uniform, it compiles fine.

Why is this a problem and what can I do to get around it?

Comment: I've had trouble with this sort of thing in the past. Honestly I can't remember how I fixed it, but I would start by making your call stack shallower:

`Test t = u_test.t;`
`float val = get_value(t);`
`fs_color = vec4(val,0.0,0.0,1.0);` It'll make debugging far simpler. You can optimise later.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that got rid of the error! Still don't quite understand why it happens in the first place though.

Comment: It's something to do with nested functions I think. Try running the original version through glslvalidator.exe and see what it tells you.